# What advantages might the Reed-Kellogg diagramming method provide over other diagramming methods?

Tags: syntax-trees, sentences

What advantages might the Reed-Kellogg diagramming method provide over other diagramming methods, and is the R-K diagramming method English specific?

Comment: I'm not trying to ask for an opinion; more what features does R-K offer that standard tree diagramming does not?

Comment: I might rephrase my topic question, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: None over tree diagrams,  Given a correctly constructed tree, the rules of the CFG required to generate it can be read off directly from the tree.  For every tree node with something dangling down from it, there must be a CF rule with the label of the node on the left side and the string of symbols dangling from it on the right side.

Comment: R-K diagrams are only useful for very simple sentences, and don't provide codings for any number of important phenomena and distinctions. Tree diagrams are more specific, but require more training to use. In fact, there is no really good standard way to convert a written sentence into a "diagram", for any language I know of. There are lots of attempts, but none that I know of work very well.